# Haskell calling HTML using Shakespeare without Yesod widgets

Tags: haskell, yesod, blaze-html, shakespeare-text

Like Yesod, so diving in deep. Have a question: using Yesod I can call eg. data type `App` with `Warp` (`warp 3000 App`).
How can I serve up HTML created using Shakespeare templates (like below). Got this from Michael Snoyman's book.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies              #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes               #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell           #-}
module Main where

import Text.Blaze.Html.Renderer.String (renderHtml) 
import Text.Hamlet (HtmlUrl, hamlet) 
import Data.Text (Text) 
import Yesod

data WebRoutes = Home | Time | Stylesheet

render :: WebRoutes -> [(Text, Text)] -> Text 
render Home _       = "/home"
render Time _       = "/time" 
render Stylesheet _ = "/stylesheet" 

template :: Text -> HtmlUrl WebRoutes 
template title = [hamlet|
<html>
  <head> 
    <title>#{varTitle} 
    <link rel=stylesheet href=@{Stylesheet}>
  <body>
    <h1 #headerId>#{title}
|]
varTitle :: String 
varTitle = "Test outputd" 

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ renderHtml $ template "Test output" render
```

Comment: It seems that I overlooked the fact that if I make a `Widget` from a Shakespearean template I can have it served up by Warp. Not sure if this is the only way though...